# Background process and read from /dev/pts/X

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, background-process, tty

I tested it on Ubuntu 12.04. First, I run java process from user1 in background and close terminal. Then I open a new terminal (from user1) run special script that sends current tty name (`/dev/pts/2`) to java process. When name receiving, comes the problem. Background process try to open `/dev/pts/2` for read - `new FileInputStream(new File("/dev/pts/2"))` and catch exception after this:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
```

But, write to this tty is worked - `new FileOutputStream(new File("/dev/pts/2"))`.

I tried to run java process as root and it's worked (read from `/dev/pts/2`)! Obviously a problem here with permissions to /dev/pts/X...

How to solve the problem of reading from any user1 terminal from background process started with user1?

```
/dev/pts
crw--w----  1 root  tty  136, 0 Jan 27 17:25 0
crw--w----  1 user1 tty  136, 1 Jan 27 19:56 1
crw--w----  1 user1 tty  136, 2 Jan 27 19:45 2
c---------  1 root  root   5, 2 Jan 27 17:25 ptmx
```

Comment: _'I run java process from user1 in background and close terminal'_ | What happens if you don't close the terminal?

Comment: Why don't you run your Java program under `screen` or `tmux` instead of doing weird things with `/dev/pts/*` ?